# How to map the output of the stored procedure to variable in SQL Task?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

In SSIS Package, I am executing the stored procedure `usp_GetResult` which returns 2 rows ( `select PathName, FolderPath from config` ).

```
PathName   : InboundFolderPath
FolderPath : c:\Inbound

PathName   : OutboundFolderPath
FolderPath : c:\Outbound
```

I will have to map the variables `@InboundFolderPath = c:\Inbound`, `@OutboundFolderPath = c:\Outbound`

How to map the output of the stored procedure to variable in SQL Task?

Comment: @TabAlleman, My apologize .. i changed to rows

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I am sorry, i changed to usp_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to do this is to use "Full Result Set" in the Execute SQL Task, and store the result in an object variable.

Then use a Script Task to convert the Object Variable to a Dataset, and iterate through it to populate your scalar variables.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really tried this but how about:

```
Declare @T Table (pathName varchar(100), folderName varchar(100))
Insert @T Exec StoredProc params  

Select max(case when PathName = 'InboundFolderPath' then folderName end ) inBound
    ,max(case when PathName = 'OutboundFolderPath' then folderName end ) outBound
from @T
```

And then map